# Certificado Digital para receber requisições HTTPS via AJAX

Tags: delphi, mormot

Alguém sabe que tipo de certificado digital é necessário para usar no *mormot* para receber requisições *AJAX* via *HTTPS*?

Além disso, como instalá-lo no windows?

Se tiverem um exemplo (preferencialmente usando ***Delphi Tokyo* + *Mormot***) agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa de um certificado de aplicação ou certificado para servidor, primeiro.

Depois, para instalar, você só precisa indicar no arquivo de configuração SSL/TLS do seu servidor de aplicação que você está usando HTTPS, geralmente é necessário redirecionar da as requisições HTTP da porta 80 para HTTPS na porta 443; além disso, você deve indicar o caminho onde você armazenou a chave-privada do seu certificado, indicar o caminho onde você armazenou o certificado no servidor e a [cadeia do seu certificado](https://blog.bry.com.br/o-que-e-uma-autoridade-certificadora-e-quais-sao-confiaveis/) (cadeia de autoridades certificadoras que assinam cada certificado de cada cadeia, incluindo o seu).

Eu não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer em Delphi, só em Apache e JBOSS, mas [**na documentação do mORMot tem algo sobre isso**](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_122).

> "O que eu ouço, eu esqueço. O que eu vejo, eu lembro. O que eu faço, eu entendo." **Confúcio**

Procure saber mais sobre o assunto.

Lembre-se de que o certificado digital protege contra ataques do tipo [man-in-the-middle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle), no entanto, não encripta dados, apenas garante autenticidade, a integridade e a validade jurídica. Veja o que fala a [Medida Provisória 2200-2/2001](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/mpv/antigas_2001/2200-2.htm).